# Are mods in the "mods tab" spare?

Tags: fallout-4

I've made a lot of weapon mods and now I need to cut down on weight. I've got a number of weapon mods in the inventory/mods window. Are these spare or are they the ones on my weapons?

What I'm asking is: can I scrap them?

Answer (score 3):

Mods in your inventory are mods that have been removed from weapons. These are not the mods currently attached to the weapons in your inventory.

Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a direct method of scrapping them, either through the various stores or by dropping the item and scrapping it in Workshop mode. However, if you have the Scrapper perk, putting mods onto a weapon before scrapping it will change the components you get back from scrapping the weapon.

Comment: You can scrap them by putting them on a weapon and scrapping the weapon.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I'm pretty much positive that those are either extras from scrapped weapons or extras from when you have changed a modification on a weapon and it keeps the one it previously had. The only downside is that you will have to build another mod from scratch if you want to switch it back. But materials are so common you won't have to worry too much about finding components.

Comment: So hang on... I have mods that can never be used?

Comment: No no you can reuse those mods in your inventory, I'm just saying that it is beneficial to store them because you might get a weapon that you want to upgrade and then bam you don't even have to craft the mod because you already had it.

Comment: Worth noting: when you scrap a weapon its mods disappear. So the mods in your inventory are only those that have been replaced by other mods, not scrapped.